# Giving a set of tuples (value,cost),Is there an algorithm to find the combination of tuple that have the least cost for storing given number

Tags: algorithm

I have a set of (value,cost) tuples which is (2000000,200) , (500000,75) , (100000,20)

Suppose X is any positive number.

Is there an algorithm to find the combination of tuple that have the least cost for the sum of value that can store X.

The sum of tuple values can be equal or greater than the given X

ex.

giving x = 800000 the answer should be (500000,75) , (100000,20) , (100000,20) , (100000,20)

giving x = 900000 the answer should be (500000,75) , (500000,75)

giving x = 1500000 the answer should be (2000000,200)

I can hardcode this but the set and the tuple are subject to change so if this can be substitute with well-known algorithm it would be great.

Comment: Your examples are not clear (the first one shows that the sum of values = x, while in the 2nd and 3rd examples there is no relation between x and the sum of values).

Comment: The sum of tuple values can be equal or greater than the given X.I'll add that into the question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be solved with dinamic programming, as you have no limit on number of tuples and can afford higher sums that provided number.

First, you can optimize tuples. If one big tuple can be replaced by number of smaller ones with equal or lower cost and equal or higher value, you can remove bigger tuple at all. 
Also, it's fruitful for future use to order tuples in optimized set by value/cost in descending order. Tuple is better if value/cost is bigger.

Time complexity O(N*T), where N is number divided by common factor (F) of optimized tuple values, and T is number of tuples in optimized tuple set.
Memory complexity O(N).

Set up array a of size N that will contain:

- in a[i].cost best cost for solution for i*F, 0 for special case "no solution yet"
- in a[i].tuple the tuple that led to best solution

Recursion scheme:

- function gets n as a single parameter - it's provided number/F for start, leftover of needed value/F sums for recusion calls
- if array a for n is filled, return a[n].cost
- otherwise set current_cost to MAXINT
- for each tuple from best to worst try to add it to solution:
- if value/F >= n, we've got some solution, compare tuple cost to current_cost and if it's better, update a[n].cost and a[n].tuple
- if value/F < n, call recursively for n-value/F and compare cost with current solution, update current solution and a[n].cost, a[n].tuple if needed
- after all, return a[n].cost or throw exception is no solution exists

Tuple list can be retrieved from a but traverse through .tuple on each step.

It's possible to reduce overall array size down to max(tuple.value/F), but you'll have to save more or less complete solution instead of one best .tuple for each element, and you'll have to make "sliding window" carefully.
It's possible to turn recursion into cycle from 0 to n, as with many other dynamic programming algorithms.

Comment: Im reading algorithm design book about dynamic programming after I saw your answer.They use weighted interval scheduling within limited time frame problem to elaborate this algorithm which is pretty much the same thing as my problem.Thank you for shedding some light!